# Как создать батник (.bat), который будет нажиать комбинацию клавиш?

Tags: windows, bat

Нужен скрипт бат фаила который будет запускаться TaskScheduler-ом при простое системы.
Сам скрип батника должен содержать в себе командду которая нажимает определенную комбинацию клавишь (Ctrl + Alt + L). Данная комбинация нужна для того что бы написанная программа (уже таковая имеется) отключала только 1 монитор из 2. Программа запускается так же TaskScheduler-ом.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот нашел пример на другом форуме:

через обертку на JS
(всё в батник)

```
@set @x=0; /*
@echo off
cscript //nologo //e:jscript "%~f0"
 
::Здесь конец кода батника
exit /b
*/
 
var wshShell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
var success = wshShell.AppActivate("MathCad");
while (!success) {
   success = wshShell.AppActivate("MathCad");
   WScript.Sleep(200);
}
wshShell.SendKeys("^S");
WScript.Quit();
```